# AJAX HTTP Request issue with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie in AJAX and i tried to make a simple MySQL query in AJAX but it doesn't work, the response is a 500 Internal Server error.

I searched for the answer on this forum and other websites but i've never found an answer for my problem.

Basically, on my app, the user writes a pseudo and click on 'play', and an AJAX function is called onClick, a function that make a simple MySQL query :

```
$.ajax({
            url: "check_pseudo.php",
            method: "GET",
            data : { pseudo : input},
            error: function() {
                alert("Une erreur est survenue");
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
```

PHP / MySQL :

```
$pseudo = $_GET["pseudo"];

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT ? FROM pseudo');
$req->execute(array($pseudo));

$reponse = $req->fetch();

if ($reponse) {
    echo "This pseudo does exist";
}else{
    echo "Pseudo not found";
}
```

This code sends me 'GET http://localhost:8888/check_pseudo.php?pseudo=oianf 500 (Internal Server Error)' in the console debugger.

How could i solve this problem?

Merci :)

Comment: 500 server error, something is wrong in your PHP. Try replacing your `$req->execute(array($pseudo));` with `$req->bind_param('s', $pseudo); $req->execute();`. If that does not solve it, try removing parts of your PHP code, from bottom to top, until you get no 500 error, to find the curlpit. Or look at your server logs.

Comment: The query should probably be `SELECT * FROM pseudo WHERE someColumn = ?`

Comment: Or maybe `SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE pseudo = ?`

Comment: @Barmar I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT ? FROM pseudo');
$req->execute(array($pseudo));
```

Using `prepare()` with a `?` in it builds a query expecting additional input. You need to fill that `?` with something. (check out [PHP's mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)).

You need to do something like:

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT ? FROM pseudo');
$req->bind_param("s", $pseudo);
$req->execute();
```

...but even that doesn't quite seem right. Usually we wouldn't be passing the fields to be selected inside query params. We would usually do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "users.php",
  method: "GET",
  data : {user_id: input_id},
  error: function() {
    alert("Error! ...Something went wrong.");
  },
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
```

Then inside `users.php` we would have:

```
$user_id = $_GET["user_id"];    
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where user_id=?');
$req->bind_param("i", $user_id);
$req->execute(); 
$reponse = $req->fetch();

if ($reponse) {
    echo "This user does exist";
} else {
    echo "User not found";
}
```